# problem with uploading the image to url in android

Tags: android, url, upload, camera

in my app i am trying to capture an image and i want to send it to an url, but the problem is when the activity is started and the camera is opened, before i am capturing the image the uploading to server part gets started and because of this the image is not been uploaded.

Following is my code, pls help me to solve the issue...

```
public class Camera extends Activity
{
    protected static final int TAKE_RECEIPT = 0;
    private Uri imageCaptureUri;
    private String filename;
    private Runnable submitReceiptRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            publishReceipt();
        }

        private void publishReceipt()
        {

        }
    };

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    OutputStream outStream;

    Intent myIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);

        takePictureFromCamera();
    }
            private void takePictureFromCamera()
            {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_receipt_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageCaptureUri);
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_RECEIPT);

                    String path =  String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis());
                    try
                    {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        doFileUpload(path);
                        Log.e("Camera",""+outStream);
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


            }

            private void takeReceiptCallback(int resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    submitReceipt();
                }
            }

            private void submitReceipt()
            {
                Thread thread = new Thread(null, submitReceiptRunnable);
                thread.start();
//                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Publishing receipt ...", true);               
            }

            private String getBase64Receipt() {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageCaptureUri);
//                    byte[] bytes = CommonUtil.getBytesFromInputStream(inputStream);
//                    return Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);//(selectedImage.getPath().getBytes());    
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Log.e("getbase64Reciept", ""+e);
                }

                return null;
            }

            private void publishReceipt()
            {
                String receipt = getBase64Receipt();
            }



            private void doFileUpload(String exsistingFileName)
            {
                  HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                  DataOutputStream dos = null;
                  DataInputStream inStream = null;

                  String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                  String twoHyphens = "--";
                  String boundary =  "*****";


                  int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;

                  byte[] buffer;

                  int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

                  String responseFromServer = "";

                  String urlString = "http://demo.great.com/spot/upload.php";

                  try
                  {
                   //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST

                  Log.e("MediaPlayer","Inside second Method");

                  FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(exsistingFileName));

                  URL url = new URL(urlString);

                  conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                  // Allow Inputs
                  conn.setDoInput(true);

                  // Allow Outputs
                  conn.setDoOutput(true);

                  // Don't use a cached copy.
                  conn.setUseCaches(false);

                  // Use a post method.
                  conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                  dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream() );

                  dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                  dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + exsistingFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                  dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                  Log.e("MediaPlayer","Headers are written");

                  // create a buffer of maximum size
                  bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                  bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                  buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                  // read file and write it into form...
                  bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                  while (bytesRead > 0)
                  {
                      dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                      bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                      bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                      bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                  }

                  // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...

                  dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                  dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // close streams
                   Log.e("MediaPlayer","File is written");
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

                  }
                  catch (MalformedURLException ex)
                  {
                       Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                  }

                  catch (IOException ioe)
                  {
                       Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                  }

                  //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE

                  try {
                        inStream = new DataInputStream ( conn.getInputStream() );
                        String str;

                        while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                             Log.e("MediaPlayer","Server Response"+str);
                        }
                        inStream.close();

                  }
                  catch (IOException ioex){
                       Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                  }       
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a function that gets the result from

```
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_RECEIPT);
```

You need to implement this method:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```